# How do I get select2 to work for two classes? It just initialize the second class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2

I tried to use Select2 with two different classes. The both classes are used for different forms. One of them is for the desktop and the other is for the mobile form. The problem is that just the second class is working as expected. What i want is to use select2 for two select fields.

> Jquery Version:  **jQuery v3.6.4**
>
> Select2 Version: **Select2 4.1.0-rc.0**

**Javascript Code:**

```
<script>
    // Initialisiere Select2
    $('.select2-icons-mobile, .select2-icons-desktop').select2({
        templateResult: formatOption,
        templateSelection: formatSelection,
        escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m; },
        minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity
    });

    function formatOption(option) {
        if (!option.id) {
            return option.text;
        }

        var icon = getIconForOption(option);

        var $option = $('<span><i class="bi ' + option.text + ' mx-2"></i>' + icon + '</span>');

        return $option;
    }

    function formatSelection(selection) {
        var icon = getIconForOption({ text: selection.text });

        var $selection = $('<span><i class="bi ' + selection.text + '"></i></span>');

        return $selection;
    }

    function getIconForOption(option) {
        if (!option.text) {
            return "";
        }

        // Prüfe den Text direkt für die mobile Auswahl
        if (option.text == "Produkt" || option.text == "bi-stack") {
            return "Produkt";
        } else if (option.text == "Generation" || option.text == "bi-x-diamond-fill") {
            return "Generation";
        } else if (option.text == "Set" || option.text == "bi-collection-fill") {
            return "Set";
        } else if (option.text == "Shop" || option.text == "bi-shop-window") {
            return "Shop";
        } else if (option.text == "Community" || option.text == "bi-people-fill") {
            return "Community";
        }

        return "";
    }
</script>
```

**HTML Code:**

```
    <!-- MOBILE FORM -->
    <form class="d-flex" method="post" action="{{ url_for('main.search_results') }}">
        {{ search_form.hidden_tag() }}
        
        {{ search_form.search_type(class="form-control select2-icons-mobile") }}

        {{ search_form.search_string.label }}
        <div class="w-100 form-group position-relative mb-0 d-flex">
            {{ search_form.search_string(class="form-control rounded-0", placeholder="Auf PokeCheck suchen") }}
        </div>
        
        {{ search_form.submit() | safe }}
    </form>
```

```
                <!-- DEKSTOP FORM -->
                <form class="d-flex" method="post" action="{{ url_for('main.search_results') }}">
                    {{ search_form.hidden_tag() }}

                    {{ search_form.search_type.label(class="form-control d-hide") }}
                    {{ search_form.search_type(class="form-control select2-icons-desktop") }}

                    {{ search_form.search_string.label }}
                    <div class="form-group position-relative mb-0">
                        {{ search_form.search_string(class="form-control desktop-form", placeholder="Auf PokeCheck suchen") }}
                    </div>
                    
                    {{ search_form.submit() | safe }}
                </form>
```

What I tried so far was splitting it into two sectors like:

```
$('.select2-icons-mobile').select2({
    templateResult: formatOption,
    templateSelection: formatSelection,
    escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m; },
    minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity
});

$('.select2-icons-desktop').select2({
    templateResult: formatOption,
    templateSelection: formatSelection,
    escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m; },
    minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity
});
```

but i got the same bug. Just the second sector is working and the first is not. At the frontend i see that `Select2` completely ignores the first `sector( .select2-icons-mobile )`.

How do I get select2 to work for two classes?

Comment: Are you saying that using a jQuery object with multiple selectors to initialise multiple Select2 instances isn't working for you? Because it should, and does work: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/oq9gw8tL/. What debugging have you done? I'd suggest starting by checking the console for errors raised elsewhere in your codebase.

Comment: Are both those fields actually part of the DOM already, when your code executes? Do a `console.log($('.select2-icons-mobile').length)` in that place, and check what result you get.

Comment: Hello Rory and Cbroe,
the strange thing is that I didn't get any kind of errors. The console and server-side logs are empty while debugging.

"console.log($('.select2-icons-mobile').length)" gave me the output: 1

Take a look at https://dev.pokecheck.de/index and you will see that ".myselect1" the mobile form didn't get initialized with Select2. Just the desktop form ".myselect2".

I updated the code with the answer below without success.